# Which number is higher $2^{600}$ or $3^{400}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, real-numbers

> Which number is higher $2^{600}$ or $3^{400}$ ?

I know that the solution is $3^{400}>2^{600}$ bot how to explain that.
without using a calculator.

Comment: In this case Sami's or math110 answers works perfectly and without approximations, but a more general method for less nice bases and exponents is to compare them to power of $10$, $2^{10}\approx 10^3$ so $2^{600}\approx 10^{180}$ while $3^2\approx 10$ so $3^{400} \approx 10^{200}$

Comment: You need to be a little careful: $2^{10} > 10^{3}$ and $3^{2} < 10.$ So you get $2^{600} >> 10^{180}$ and $3^{400} << 10^{200}.$

Answer (score 8):

Hint
$$3^2>2^3\Longrightarrow 3^4>2^6\Longrightarrow 3^{400}>2^{600}$$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**

Compare $2^6$ and $3^4$ and notice that the function $x\mapsto x^{100}$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Increasing on the positive axis!

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion - apply $\sqrt[200]{\dots}$ on each one of the expressions:

- $\sqrt[200]{2^{600}}=2^{\frac{600}{200}}=2^3=8$
- $\sqrt[200]{3^{400}}=3^{\frac{400}{200}}=3^2=9$